# connection refused while connecting to upstream Nginx Docker

Tags: docker, nginx, fastapi

I'm trying to build a FastAPI app in docker, I find the site comes to a '502-Bad Gate Way' error and nginx log shows:

```
nginx_1    | 2020/12/21 18:23:13 [error] 29#29: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.27.0.1, server: , request: "GET /user HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.27.0.3:8000/user", host: "localhost:8080"
```

Here is my docker-compose.yaml file:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  fastapi:
    build: ./api
    command: uvicorn main:app --reload --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000
    volumes:
      - ./fastapi/:/fastapi/
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: mongo4
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - "./data/mongo/data:/data/db"

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx_config.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
      - fastapi
```

Nginx config file:

```
server {
  listen 8080;

  location /user {
    proxy_pass http://fastapi:8000/user;
  }
}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: You get a `502` if the proxy cannot talk to the backend service. You should check the state of the fastapi container, look at it's logs, etc…

Comment: Try to curl the upstream machine at http://172.27.0.3:8000/user from the server where Nginx is hosted.